# How to get newData key for Firebase Rules?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Here is very simple rule for users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $userId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course it's not working when we want to create new user, and here is my question, how to create rule which will be checking if new key in `users` path will be the same as `auth.uid`?

**Update**

I need something like this line `".write": "auth.uid === $userId"` below `".read": true` but here is impossible because it wouldn't see `$userId` variable.

In my case this should work:

- Location: `/users`
- Data: `{ "user1" : { "name": tester" } }`
- UID: `user1`

but this shouldn't:

- Location: `/users`
- Data: `{ "user1" : { "name": tester" } }`
- UID: `user2`

Comment: This rule ensures that only the currently signed in user can edit their own data. I don't really understand your reference to a *new* key. Can you give an example of code that you'd want to allow, and code that you'd want to be disallowed?

Comment: Have you tried your rule?  It allows a user to create, update, or remove data under his/her `userId` only.  That seems to be what you want.

Comment: But it doesn't allow to create userId first.

Comment: Keys/paths in the Firebase Database are created automatically as data is written to that path. Your current rules allow the write to the paths with the first data and disallow the second. Unless you have some actual code that is failing, but that should be allowed, there is not a lot we can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid) || data.hasChild(auth.uid)",
        "$userId": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $userId"
        }
    }
  }
}
```